# RGB Color not showing

Tags: three.js

I have some normalized points for (Red, Blue, Green). When I convert them to RGB, I get values such as:

```
R: 0.23
G: 0.44
B: 0.33
```

However, this is not showing up as any color but white when I color my face on my tubegeometry. This happens to almost all RGB values except the main ones such as `255, 0, 0` or `0, 255, 0`

```
var rVal = parseFloat(rLow + normalizedGr * (rHigh - rLow));
var gVal = parseFloat(gLow + normalizedGr * (gHigh - gLow));
var bVal = parseFloat(bLow + normalizedGr * (bHigh - bLow));

var logColor = new THREE.Color().setRGB(rVal, gVal, bVal);

for (var j = startingPoint; j < endingPoint; j++) {
          tube.faces[j].color = logColor;
}

 var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(tube, [new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: color, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors })]);
```

Comment: Show some code so we can see how you pass the color to the geometry.

Comment: @gaitat I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color setRGB( r, g, b ) sets the color from RGB values between 0 and 1.

Comment: My values are normalized so they are between 0 and 1, however, I have the same problem.